# Distinguish single click from double click C++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mouse, double-click

I have an application in which double clicking over an image view area changes the layout of the image view. Also on single click a dot will be placed on the image.
My problem is, both functionality is working when double clicked.

Of course I know that, when a double click occurs the control first goes to LButtonDown. I don't want the dot functionality to work when double click occurs. I have been working around this for more than a week. Please help.

Comment: look up CS_DBLCLKS. It is the quick and dirty way to deal with this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to build a [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) for handling mouse clicks.
Basically, this will be a singleton object, which takes input from the mouse click events you're currently using.
It's output will be `SingleClickDetected, DoubleClickDetected, ...`.
Red arrows indicate events which you are reporting to the rest of your application.
Parentheses indicate what event you are reporting.

[image: FSM]

Of course, this state machine will have to be modified if you have to deal directly with `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events, instead of `MouseClick` events.
It will be slightly larger, but the idea is basically the same.

EDIT:
From the comments, it looks like Windows doesn't cleanly report single- vs double-clicks, and you need to separate them.
A state-machine for this scenario:
[image: FSM2]

This is probably overkill for what you're trying to do, especially since most, if not all GUI-based programs in the history of everything have never *ever* used a double-click drag.
It does show the basic idea, and shows how you can extend your state machine to handle different types of button clicks.
Furthermore, if you wanted to, you could handle double-right-clicks, a drag that involves both left and right buttons, or any other scenario you could think of and incorporate into your UI.

Comment: [from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645606(v=vs.85).aspx) Double-clicking the left mouse button actually generates a sequence of four messages: WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, and WM_LBUTTONUP

Comment: Thank you for the response. But could not figure out what you actually meant. Because when control enters LbuttonDown for the first time, we cannot ensure whether the user is gonna single click or double click. This is the real issue.

Comment: @VipinPaul This is the exact issue my solution is dealing with. Each black arrow deals with transforming a library-, operating system-, or API-supplied input, into an output for the rest of your program to deal with. So, your program **never** touches LButtonDown itself anymore. Only the one mouse-handling subsystem will touch those inputs, and then provide unambiguous mouse clicks for the rest of your program. If you don't know how to read a FSM diagram, you basically just follow the arrows around and around and around. I also recommend fully reading the Wikipedia article, and some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following code and it works.

```
UINT TimerId;
int clicks;

    VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime)
    {
        KillTimer(NULL, TimerId);
        if (clicks < 2 && !double_click){
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Show Widget", L"Widget", MB_OK);
        }

        clicks = 0;
    }



  LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {

        int wmId, wmEvent;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc;
        TCHAR szHello[MAX_LOADSTRING];
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_HELLO, szHello, MAX_LOADSTRING);
        UINT uID;
        UINT uMouseMsg;

        uID = (UINT)wParam;
        uMouseMsg = (UINT)lParam;

        if (uMouseMsg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK){
            double_click = true;
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Double click", L"CAPT", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }
        if (uMouseMsg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN){
            double_click = false;
            clicks++;

            //single click opens context menu
            if (clicks == 1){
                TimerId = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 500, &TimerProc);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    ,...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the timestamp of the last LButtonDown; if the time difference between the last timestamp and the timestamp produced in the current event is too short, you can just cancel your operation (but still store the new LButtonDown timestamp)

Comment: But for a double click event, the control enters in LbuttonDown only once.The next time it enters in LBtnDoubleClick. So I think storing timestamp value is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is wait for a short amount of time each time you receive click event, and test if in the meantime the equivalent of a double click event doesn't occur before performing the single click response. This  may be source to new bugs and unresponsive UI. Maybe try to change the user interaction to toss the problem away.

EDIT: The fact that you are working around this for more than a week is a symptom of bad user interaction design. A "double click" still means two clicks occurs, which means the application naturally should perform the operation of a single click. Check the ui of the apps installed on your desktop to verify this. Have you considered using a different user medium to trigger the UI response? For instance, you can use the right button to put the dot on the image.

Comment: Actually, a double click is always a separate thing from a single click. It's been like that since the early days of Windows, Mac, etc. Yes, a double click invloves two presses of the mouse button. No, it is not appropriate to perform the single-click action twice. The only time that would be appropriate is when the threshold time for a double click has been exceeded, and two distinct single click events are detected.

Comment: Applicationwise, if the platform doesn't deliver you events directly as either `click` or `doubleclick` (**never** both) it is not a separate thing.

Comment: Then that's a problem with the library in question, and needs to be dealt with as such, because it does not allow the application developer to easily distinguish between single and double clicks. Use an alternate library, or go lower-level in whatever API you're working with. Alternately, you can use the reported events to build a finite-state machine to clean up the reported clicks into click detection that actually works properly.

Comment: My point : receiving a `doubleclick` always means that you received the equivalent of a `click`. Because of this correlation you cannot say that `a double click is always a separate thing from a single click`. ps: I never said the action of a click should be performed ***twice***

Answer (score 0):

@E.T's answer is spot-on. To implement something like that, you really need a timer running along with your message loop.

In my application I wanted to be able to distinguish mouse down/up from double click because I want a double click to not undo a drag operation (imagine selection box with left button drag and double click to zoom to fit).

The following code does this using `PreTranslateMessage`. I did not add the timer out of laziness. So the UI behaves a bit "funny" if you don't immediately move the mouse after the left button is held down. In my case, this is a minor issue.

```
BOOL MyWindow::PreTranslateMessage(MSG *pMsg)
{
//From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645606(v=vs.85).aspx
//Double-clicking the left mouse button actually generates a sequence of four messages: 
//WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, and WM_LBUTTONUP

//So here's the problem. If an button up message arrives, we can't just
//take it, because it may be followed by a double click message. So we check
//for this.

//Ideally you need a timer - what happens if you don't get any messages
//after the button up or down? But here we get lazy and assume a message
//will come "soon enough".

static bool upMessageStored = false;
static bool dnMessageStored = false;
static MSG upMessage, dnMessage;
static bool processDnNow = false, processUpNow = false;

//This logic sequence absorbs all button up and down messages, storing them to be sent
//if something other than a double click message immediately follows.

if (!(pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK ||
      pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN ||
      pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONUP) &&
    (upMessageStored || dnMessageStored))
{
    //If we receive any message other than double click and we've stored the messages,
    //then post them.
    Output::Message(L"Stored messages posted.\n");
    if (upMessageStored)
    {
        processUpNow = true;
        upMessageStored = false;
        this->PostMessage(upMessage.message, upMessage.wParam, upMessage.lParam);
    }
    if (dnMessageStored)
    {
        processDnNow = true;
        dnMessageStored = false;
        this->PostMessage(dnMessage.message, dnMessage.wParam, dnMessage.lParam);
    }
    return TitlelessWindow::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN && !processDnNow)
{
    Output::Message(L"WM_LBUTTONDOWN absorbed; message stored\n");
    dnMessage = *pMsg;
    dnMessageStored = true;
    return TRUE; //swallow this message.
}
else if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONUP && !processUpNow)
{
    Output::Message(L"WM_LBUTTONUP absorbed; message stored\n");
    upMessage = *pMsg;
    upMessageStored = true;
    return TRUE; //swallow this message.
}
else if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
{
    Output::Message(L"WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK; stored message discarded\n");
    upMessageStored = false;
    dnMessageStored = false;
    processUpNow = false;
    processDnNow = false;
}

//If we get here, we are processing messages normally. Be sure we clear the flags
//for up and down.
processDnNow = false;
processUpNow = false;
return ParentClass::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really liked the finite state machine answer BUT there is a flaw in it.
There is no such thing as "single click time" which you can exceed.

If you look at a the working of your mouse closely you will see that:-

single click not one event but =  WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP which is independent of time in between, the appropriate action will take place anyway

Double-clicking the left mouse button actually generates a sequence of four messages: WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, and WM_LBUTTONUP
so you should use the 3rd flag to your advantage

BTW, I am also working on something like this. Thanks!