# How to distinguish the WM_LBUTTONUP message in a single-click event and a double-click event

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I want to do something when I receive the WM_LBUTTONUP message in the single-click event, but the WM_LBUTTONUP message in the double-click event should not do these things. How can I ignore it in the function OnLButtonUp() that processes the message?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Code doesn't help. The issue is a logical challenge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distinguish single click from double click C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226791/distinguish-single-click-from-double-click-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer doesn't have clairvoyant super powers and thus cannot reliably predict whether any observed `WM_LBUTTONUP` is or isn't followed up by any `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message.

What you *could* do is start a timer in your `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message handler with a timeout of [`GetDoubleClickTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdoubleclicktime), and build up a complex state machine that moves between states on `WM_TIMER`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`, and `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` messages.

That's doable, but a lot more complex than you'd expect. Plus, it will necessarily introduce a delay between the user releasing the left mouse button and the action they intended to trigger starting.

What you *should* be doing instead is solving your UX issue. If you make your single click action unrelated to your double click action, then that is the bug that needs to be addressed. [Logical consequences of the way Windows converts single-clicks into double-clicks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041015-00/?p=37553) goes into much more detail, and arrives at the same conclusion: Don't, just don't do it.